# Gitolite push error for gitolite-admin

Tags: gitolite

When i try to push the repository gitolite-admin it gives me below error

```
Counting objects: 7, done.  
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 360 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.  
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects a  bnormal exit  
To http://server.name/git/gitolite-admin.git  
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://server.name/git/gitolite-admin.git'
```

Below is my apache log

```
[Mon Sep 02 08:39:50 2013] [error] [client ] error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
[Mon Sep 02 08:39:50 2013] [error] [client ] fatal: failed to write object
```

Your Help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure of the user accessing your gitolite repos behind your Apache.

Then, following this [blog post](http://mapopa.blogspot.fr/2009/10/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding.html):

```
ssh to server
cd repository.git

sudo chmod -R g+ws *
sudo chgrp -R mygroup *

git repo-config core.sharedRepository true
```

Comment: I am getting below error now  remote: FATAL: open conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm.new failed: Permission denied

Comment: @user2164525 not much to add as this is again a user right issue. I don't know what exact user id is behind those gitolite process, but you should be able to find the right one, and make the appropriate changes.

Comment: i am getting this error open conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm.new failed: Permission denied<<newline>> system() failed,gitolite compile,-> 6400 unable to identify, from where this error is coming. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: @user2164525 again, what is the user executing the gitolite process? Ie what is the complete ssh url you are using to push to `gitolite-admin` repo?

Comment: I did the changes what you mentioned above and i was able to push by adding new users to the testing repo. Now I have added a new repo in gitolite.conf, but it is not creating the repo in the server. the user is apache. The url is http://server.name/git/gitolite-admin.git. The protocol which i am using is http

Comment: @user2164525 ok, then this original question should be closed (accepted), and you should detail the new error in a separate question, with as many details as possible, for me or others to have a look.